# iOS CoreData error after implementing ARC

Tags: ios, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

We have recently performed a conversion of our iOS application to use ARC and 64-bit.  Everything works fine when installing/running the app on a device that doesn't have the previous version installed.  If there is a previous version then CoreData is throwing an error saying "Can't find model for source store".

- We have not made any changes to the model.
- The .xcdatamodeld file is unchanged when viewing the history in GIT.
- The Entity classes have changed in regards to the property declarations going from *assign* to *strong* during the ARC conversion

Has anyone experienced this behaviour before that was not related to model changes?